# .htaccess doesn't rewrite /something to index.php?menu=something. It shows something.htm instead

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want my site to treat URI as part of a query string.
When accessing properly with **sub.domain.cz/something** it works okay.
If I don't use neither **www** nor **sub**, it rewrites URL and works.
But when I use **www**, it rewrites **www.domain.cz** to **sub.domain.cz**, but it shows **sub.domain.cz/something.htm** instead of threating **'something'** like parameter.

I thought there is the problem with multiple use, but adding `Options -MultiViews` didn't change anything (and removing `!-f` makes it lose connection to styles).

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.cz$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.cz/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=style.css
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?menu=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I'm not any expert. Mostly I'm just trying a bunch of stuff I find on Internet and simultaneously trying to understand them for future use. But now I have no idea of what's wrong. I've tried changing order and flags. Maybe all of that changed something but it was not visible to me. Do you have any nice idea, please?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.cz$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.cz/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /something/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=style.css
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?menu=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Now I'm wondering if my English is that bad and I couldn't tell what I really want or that solution is not sutable for me. There is a bunch of stuff that can be placed after sub.domain.cz like intro/price/about-us/offer, so 'something' isn't the only parameter I'm having troubles with. And I can't make RewriteBase for everyone of them (or can I?).
I may be a rookie, but how is that supposed to help the problem exactly? I don't have a folder /something/, so there are no rules for it need.